# node.js promise sequence

Tags: node.js, promise

During testing node.js promise framework. I got a strange result.
here is a code.

```
var Promise = require('promise');

var fs = require('fs');
var src = '/tmp/myfile.txt';
var des = '/tmp/myfile_promise2.txt';

var fread = Promise.denodeify(fs.readFile);
var fwrite = Promise.denodeify(fs.writeFile);

fread(src)
        .then(
            function(text){
                console.log('Read done');
                return fwrite(des,text);
            })
        .then(console.log('Write done'))
        .catch(function(reason){
            console.log('Read or Write file error');
            console.log(reason);
        });
```

File is successfully written. But console output is like below

> Write done
>   Read done

My expected result is, print "Read done" first and then "Write done".
What was wrong?

Comment: `.then(console.log('Write done'))` this log call is not wrapped in a function.

Comment: You're calling `console.log('Write done')` already when setting up the promise chain, it should instead be wrapped in a function so it gets called by `then`.

Comment: have you tried using a 
var myFile;
try{
myFile = fs.readFileSync(pathToFile, 'utf8', 'r');
if(typeof myFile == 'object' && myFile.length){
fs.writeFileSync(pathToNewFile, JSON.stringify(myFile), 'utf8', function(err){
if(err) console.log(err);
}

Comment: @Zargold that isn't helpful at all. The point of using promises is to make a chain of asynchronous operations.

Comment: ok if you absolutely need it to be async... but once you're waiting for process 1 to finish then what's the point. But you guys are right that it should be in a function... I just like my strategy.

Comment: @Zargold We don't know in what context this snippet will be in, and synchronous operations would block everything else. Besides, the matter of sync vs async is out of this question.

Answer (score 3):

Thanx @E_net4 ^ @Joachim Isakkson

After wrapping it with function, it works.
I need to learn promise creation life cycle again.

```
var Promise = require('promise');

var fs = require('fs');
var src = '/tmp/myfile.txt';
var des = '/tmp2/myfile_promise2.txt';

var fread = Promise.denodeify(fs.readFile);
var fwrite = Promise.denodeify(fs.writeFile);

fread(src)
.then(
        function(text){
            console.log('Read done');
            return fwrite(des,text); // 체이닝을 하려면 return을 해줘야 함. 
        })
        .then(function(){
            console.log('Write done');
        })
        .catch(function(reason){
            console.log('Read or Write file error');
            console.log(reason);
        });
```